# Объединить struct-массивы в 1 массив

Tags: c#, массивы, struct

Доброго времени суток. Есть некий структурный тип данных:

```
public struct Global  
{  
    public byte[] Control;  
    public byte[] address;  
    public byte[] Data;  
};
```

Его необходимо послать через функцию `socket.send`, причем 1 пакетом. Судя по всему, для этого необходимо соединить все 3 массива в один. Это можно сделать через циклы, присваивая значения поэлементно, по всей длине массивов, но хотелось бы узнать, может быть есть другой способ сделать это проще и быстрее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`System.Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx). Он и достаточно быстр и не требует написания своих велосипедов. Можно также попробовать Array.Copy, но, насколько знаю, для примитивных типов BlockCopy работает несколько быстрее

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, к вашим услугам метод [`Array.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx). Он копирует элементы из одного массива в другой чуть быстрее, чем это было бы сделано циклом.

Если структура данных оказывается более сложной - то более простым способом может оказаться создание [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) и запись туда данных, с последующим извлечением данных обратно методом [`ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx)

Дополнительное удобство можно получить, обернув поток в [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx), который позволяет записывать в поток не только массивы байт, но и числа или строки.